# OpenCV window is freezing

Tags: c++, c, qt, opencv, tcp

I am trying to display frames that are sent via TCP.
Everything is working fine and I can see the frames in real time.

The problem is that after a time the window is freezing, if I close the window another window appear and it freeze after sometime.

Here is my code:

```
CvSize size;
size.height = 480;
size.width = 640;
IplImage *frame = cvCreateImageHeader(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
frame->imageData = Frame.data();
cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );
Frame.clear();
cvReleaseImage(&frame);
totalPacketsSize =0 ;
```

this code is running in a loop while receiving frames.

**Note:**
This code is running on a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [cvWaitKey(xxx)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#waitkey) after the showimage() where XXX is a reasonable amount of time for a new image to be ready (in milliseconds)

Comment: I tried cvWaitKey with 50,100 and 500 mSec and it shows only the first frame.